# How to submit a Thymeleaf form on text box value change?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, action, call

I am working on a simple application using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I want to submit the form on text box value change. I am not sure whether we can call the "th:action="@{/greeting}"" through java script?

--Here is my html greeting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}"
        method="post">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Id:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset"
                value="Reset" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

--Controller Class :: GreetingController.java

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
        greeting.setId(108);
        greeting.setContent("Welcome");
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        greeting.setId(greeting.getId()+1);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will not be aware of `th:action="@{/greeting}` since it's thymeleaf domain name. 
Instead, you can simply use the `/greeting` URL since you are in the same domain name it will directly hit your controller. An example in jquery can be like this:

`function onChange() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/greeting',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {attribute_of_greeting_1:'value_to_post_1',attribute_of_greeting_2:'value_to_post_2'}
        })
    }`

 Ad then link this function to your event.